# Python Pandas - Find rows where element is in row's array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I want to find all rows where a certain value is present inside the column's list value.

So imagine I have a `dataframe` set up like this:

```
|  placeID |                             users | 
------------------------------------------------
|    134986|   [U1030, U1017, U1123, U1044...] |
|    133986|   [U1034, U1011, U1133, U1044...] |
|    134886|   [U1031, U1015, U1133, U1044...] |
|    134976|   [U1130, U1016, U1133, U1044...] |
```

How can I get all rows where `'U1030'` exists in the users column?

Or... is the real problem that I should not have my data arranged like this, and I should instead explode that column to have a row for each user?

What's the right way to approach this?

Comment: what code did you try and how did the result of that differ from the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are wanting to check whether a value exists inside the column when the value in the column is a list, it's helpful to use the [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function.

Implementing it like below, with a lambda inline function, the list of values stored in the 'users' column is mapped to the value u, and userID is compared to it...

Really the answer is pretty straightforward when you look at the code below:

```
# user_filter filters the dataframe to all the rows where
# 'userID' is NOT in the 'users' column (the value of which
# is a list type)
user_filter = df['users'].map(lambda u: userID not in u)

# cuisine_filter filters the dataframe to only the rows
# where 'cuisine' exists in the 'cuisines' column (the value
# of which is a list type)
cuisine_filter = df['cuisines'].map(lambda c: cuisine in c)

# Display the result, filtering by the weight assigned
df[user_filter & cuisine_filter]
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you have stored data looks fine to me. You do not need to change the format of storing data.

Try this :

```
df1 = df[df['users'].str.contains("U1030")]

print(df1)
```

This will give you all the rows containing specified user in `df` format.

Comment: @Paul Does this help ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it gives me a strange keyerror when I try it. I did solve my problem, answer to be posted momentarily.